# Getting the path of a file using fileupload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using a fileupload control to display the contents of a text file in a textbox..if i use this

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="txtBoxInput" runat="server" Text="Browse" />

string FilePath = txtBoxInput.PostedFile.FileName;
```

it will get only the file name like `bala.txt`.i need like this `D:\New Folder\bala.txt`

Instead of fileupload control i have used textbox to get the path like  this `D:\New Folder\bala.txt`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxInput" runat="server" Width="451px"></asp:TextBox>

string FilePath = txtBoxInput.Text;
```

But i need browse button instead of textbox to get the path...Any Suggestion??

EDIT:My button click event

```
protected void buttonDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilePath = txtBoxInput.PostedFile.FileName;
    if (File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        StreamReader testTxt = new StreamReader(FilePath);
        string allRead = testTxt.ReadToEnd();
        testTxt.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the file name and path from FileUpload control only when you are in debug mode but when you deployed your app. in server then you cant because that is your client address which you are trying to access by server side code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath,fileName;
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
    {
        filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; // file name with path.
        fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;// Only file name.
    }
}
```

If you really want to change properties or rename client file then you can save file on server on temp folder then you can do all thing which you want.

Comment: @jeevan I have tried ur code but i got this error Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\bala.txt'

Comment: @jeevan in the file path also i get the file name only

Comment: @Aamir in the file path also i get the file name only

Comment: #Bala- can you post your button click event where you are trying to access FileUpload's file.

Comment: @Bala: I am 100% sure that you are not running you code in IE if yes then check it on IE. If you want to run on other browser then you have to configure your application for other browser.

Comment: @Bala: And the second thing, as it is clear by your code that you are trying to read client file in server with out saving it on server, so you cant do this, for this you will have to save client file in server then read it.

Comment: @Bala: Actually FileUpload control of asp.net has different behavior in different Browser so logically you should not get local file path in server side (IE behavior is not correct). think practically, you can not read client file on server side code until unless you save file on server.

Answer (score 2):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1077850.aspx